# Interpretation of a line of Fortran Code

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have been trying to figure out the meaning of these two lines of code for a while now:

```
TYPE(DGRID),TARGET,ALLOCATABLE :: DGRIDS(:)
```

...

```
JEK     => DGRIDS(IMOD)%JEK
```

I'm using Code Blocks and IMOD is shown in green font, which seems to indicate the IMOD is an intrinsic function. I understand the second line is setting a pointer, but I cannot figure out why the intrinsic function is there. I am also unclear how JEK can be used twice - do the two "JEK"s in the second line refer to different entities?

Comment: I'm not sure `IMOD` is a function, that appears to be array syntax a la `dgrids[imod]` in C for example. That's also supported by `DGRIDS(:)` which looks suspiciously like an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@paxdiablo's comment is spot on, I'll just expand a little on it in the vainglorious pursuit of rep ...

```
TYPE(DGRID),TARGET,ALLOCATABLE :: DGRIDS(:)
```

declares an array of things of type `dgrid`.  From that, and the other line shown, surely elsewhere in the code there is a declaration of which

```
type :: dgrid
    ...
    <type> :: jek
    ...
end type
```

is a recovered fragment.  So `jek` (I'm being as insensitive to case as Fortran itself) is used as the name of an element of type `dgrid`.

The line

```
JEK     => DGRIDS(IMOD)%JEK
```

associates the pointer called `jek` with the element `jek` of the `imod`-th element of the array `dgrids`.  Somewhere else in the code is a declaration like this

```
<type_of_jek>, pointer :: jek
```

If CodeBlocks tells you that `imod` is a function it's misleading you, even a function with no arguments would have to be called as `imod()`.  `imod` must be an integer.

The name `jek` is used twice, it identifies different things.  Perhaps the programmer's fingers grew tired of typing `DGRIDS(IMOD)%` repeatedly and the programmer hit upon the idea of using `jek` as a shorthand alias for `DGRIDS(IMOD)%JEK`.  With an ultra-modern compiler the same can be realised with the `associate` statement, though that is not a general replacement for Fortran pointers, just an alternative mechanism for defining aliases.

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to say "thanks" in comments, but in this case, this is so clear & helpful that I cannot stop myself. Also, I'd like to say you're 100% right about the existence of the declarations you mentioned, which I subsequently found. Damn you're good.